# How can I install git on a CentOS system without an internet connection?

Tags: linux, git, centos

I need to install git on a CentOS 5.6 64-bit system, but I do not have an internet connection, so I can't simply download it through yum.  Also, I do not have gcc installed, so I cannot build it from source, unless gcc can be installed without a connection as well.

I have searched for an RPM that I can download and transfer via flash drive, but I haven't been able to find one.  If anyone has any suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**

As per qweet's instructions, I downloaded the rpms and attempted to install them, but got the errors below:

`$ sudo rpm -i perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64.rpm`

```
warning: perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID e8562897
    file /usr/bin/a2p from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    file /usr/bin/perl from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    file /usr/bin/perl5.8.8 from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    file /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CGI.pm from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/config.h from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/sperl.o from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    file /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/Config_heavy.pl from install of perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.x86_64 conflicts with file from package perl-5.8.8-32.el5_5.2.x86_64
    #...
    #There are a bunch more files, but a 30k character limit on these posts.  All the files say the same thing.
```

`$ sudo rpm -i perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm`

```
warning: perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
error: Failed dependencies:
    git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
    perl(Error) is needed by perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
```

`$ sudo rpm -i git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm`

```
warning: git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 217521f6
error: Failed dependencies:
    perl(Error) is needed by git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
    perl(Git) is needed by git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
    perl-Git = 1.7.4.1-1.el5 is needed by git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, since Git is part of the `EPEL` repository, your only hope is to go and download it through Yum, or by traversing the repos.

Luckily for you...

**x86_64** /cent5

[git.x86_64.rpm](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/fedora/epel/5Server/x86_64/git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm)

[perl_git.x86_64.rpm](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/fedora/epel/5Server/x86_64/perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.x86_64.rpm) (dep)

[perl.x86_64](http://mirror.team-cymru.org/CentOS/5.8/os/x86_64/CentOS/perl-5.8.8-38.el5.x86_64.rpm) (dep)

**i386** /cent5

[git.i386.rpm](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/fedora/epel/5Server/i386/git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386.rpm)

[perl_git.i386.rpm](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/fedora/epel/5Server/i386/perl-Git-1.7.4.1-1.el5.i386.rpm) (dep)

[perl.i386](http://mirror.team-cymru.org/CentOS/5.7/os/i386/CentOS/perl-5.8.8-32.el5_6.3.i386.rpm) (dep)

**x86_64** /cent6

[git.x86_64.rpm](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/git-1.7.8.2-2.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm)

[perl_git.x86_64.rpm](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/perl-Git-1.7.8.2-2.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm) (dep)

[perl.x86_64](http://mirror.team-cymru.org/CentOS/6.2/os/x86_64/Packages/perl-5.10.1-119.el6_1.1.x86_64.rpm) (dep)

**i386** /cent6

[git.i386.rpm](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/git-1.7.8.2-2.el6.rfx.i686.rpm)

[perl_git.i386.rpm](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/perl-Git-1.7.8.2-2.el6.rfx.i686.rpm) (dep)

[perl.i386](http://mirror.team-cymru.org/CentOS/6.2/os/i386/Packages/perl-5.10.1-119.el6_1.1.i686.rpm)

Install perl_git first, then install git. You can do this either through `Yum` or by RPM. If you need Perl, just comment and I'll get an RPM for you.

Comment: I do believe that I need perl too.

Comment: edited with Perl RPMs

Comment: I updated the question with the errors I got when attempting to install.  It looks like perl is already installed, and that `git` requires `perl-git` and `perl-git` requires `git`

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source for GIT here:
http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.7.9.tar.gz

Then:

```
tar xvzf git-1.7.9.tar.gz
cd git-1.7.9
./configure
make
make install
cd
mkdir git-test
cd git-test
git init
```

Should a success message after this

Comment: As I stated, I do not have gcc installed.  the git source is c code, so without gcc, there is no way to compile it.

Comment: Ahh missed that sorry, installing gcc from source would be a nightmare without doing it through YUM do to all the dependencies it requires.

Comment: Your better off getting the machine on the net somehow to install the "Developer Tools" which has nearly 100 packages your going to need including GCC --- yum -y groupinstall "development tools"

Comment: Because of the nature of the system, placing it on the network is not an option.  I need to find a way to get git on the system without a network connection

Answer (score 0):

you try to install each of these rpms separately and you must intall all of these rpms in one line just like this

```
rpm -i perl-Git-1.7.3.4-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm perl-Error-0.17010-1.el5.noarch.rpm git-1.7.3.4-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm
```

Comment: this does not solve the problem listed above.  I still get the same dependency errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below the Steps I followed to install Git without internet access on the system

1. Download the desired tarball from below link, on your PC/Laptop https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/
   I used the Git-2.8, as the customer requirement was to have version >= Git-2.74
2. Connect to remote Linux system (via winscp or nay other remote connectivity tool). And Place/Move the downloaded git-XXXXXX.tar.gz file on desired location on the linux system where you want to install ‘git’.
   I placed it in Directory: /var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/
3. From command prompt go to the directory where you placed the above file and run below command to untar the package

   ```
   tar -xvzf git-2.8.0.tar.gz
   ```

CD into the directory that is newly created because of untar command above. cd git-2.8.0/

4. Verify that all the needed files and directories have been uncompressed into the above folder

   ```
   ls -ltr
   ```
5. Set the Path and Prefix variables with commands below.

   ```
   PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0/usr/bin

   PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0

   export PATH=$PATH:/var/opt/teradata/packages/Package/GIT/git-2.8.0

   make prefix=/usr/local/git all
   ```

   echo $CC
6. Run command to check the preinstall configuration checks :

   ./configure
7. Run command to install:

   make install
8. Now see it work with command:

   git --version